# Hide content if variable is empty [simple]

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

This should be easy, not sure why it's not working. The div hide is properly working if I remove if !empty. I don't want the line showing if variable is empty.

[edit: Sorry, left the index.html out]

index.html

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("input[name='animalvillas']").click(function () {
            if ($("#chkYes1").is(":checked")) {
                $("#dvanimalvillas").show();
            } else {
                $("#dvanimalvillas").hide();
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<form name="create" action="welcome.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
<span><strong>Lodge Villas - Jambo</strong></span><BR />
<label for="chkYes1">
    <input type="radio" id="chkYes1" name="animalvillas" value="Y" />
    Include
</label>
<label for="chkNo1">
    <input type="radio" id="chkNo1" name="animalvillas" value="N" checked />
    Exclude
</label>
<hr />
<div id="dvanimalvillas" style="display: none">
$<input type="text" name="animalvillas1" size="3" /> - Value Studio - Standard View (Parking View) <br>
$<input type="text" name="animalvillas2" size="3" /> - Deluxe Studio - Standard View (Water / Pool) <br>
$<input type="text" name="animalvillas3" size="3" /> - Deluxe Studio - Savanna View <br>
</div>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

welcome.php

```
    <div id="dvanimalvillas" <?php echo ($_POST['animalvillas'] == "N") ? 'style="display:none;"' : '' ; ?>>
<?php if (!empty($animalvillas1)) { ?>$<?php echo $_POST["animalvillas1"]; ?> - Value Studio - Standard View <BR><?php } ?>
<?php if (!empty($animalvillas2)) { ?>$<?php echo $_POST["animalvillas2"]; ?> - Deluxe Studio - Standard View <BR><?php } ?>
<?php if (!empty($animalvillas3)) { ?>$<?php echo $_POST["animalvillas3"]; ?> - Deluxe Studio - Savanna View <BR><?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: so `($x == 'N') || ($x == '')`?

Comment: What's the relationship between the variables and `$_POST` keys, e.g. `$animalvillas1` and `$_POST["animalvillas1"]`?

Comment: thank you for your reply, I edited the OP to include the index.html

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery...

```
If (yourVariable <= 0){
    $('dvanimalvillas').hide ();
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, I edited the OP to include the index.html. That will clarify what I'm trying to do.